# Visualizing a restriction function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, elementary-functions

So I'm doing really basic review of functions to get back into the spirit of self-study. I came across this definition that I was hoping you guys could help me visualize:

> $A \subset B, \ \  $
>
> $f:A\to B,$defined by $f(a)=a, \ \ \forall a\in A,$
>
> $ \\ g:B\to C ,$
>
> then, $g|_{A}: A\to C$ is a restriction of g to A.

My question then is how would I go about visualizing this particular function? Below is how I see it working, but maybe someone has a more elegant picture?

[image: Sorry it's not very pretty]

Thanks guys!

Comment: Well, one concern your picture raises - $g(B \setminus A)$ and $g(A)$ do not need to be disjoint.

Comment: I'm sorry, does it make sense if the functions f,g are bijective?

Comment: Maybe you can visualize it like this: there is some temperature distributed in a room. To measure this temperature at a point, you put a thermometer at that point. If you want to restrict that temperature to a ball in the room, you are only allowed to measure at points in that ball.

Comment: Well, if $f$ is bijective then $A = B$. This is presumably not what you want.  Note that the function $f$ is always an injection, and is a surjection iff $A = B$ (this is special for the inclusion function of a subset into a set containing it). It is true that $g(A)$ and $g( B \setminus A)$ are disjoint if $g$ is injective.

Comment: There's no need to be sorry. :)

Comment: That makes sense! So if $f$ is injective, and $g$ is bijective, then the picture I drew makes sense right? Thanks man

Comment: Ultimately the pictures you draw are a language for communicating with yourself. It matters that it makes sense to you... the picture you drew makes sense, but seems a little overly complicated to me if you just want to express the notion of restriction. It depends on what features you want to focus on.

Comment: That makes sense. For some reason thought it's the only picture that seems to be easy for me to see. Thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what's going on in your picture. There doesn't seem to be any mention of $g|_A$ and $g(B \setminus A)$ need not be disjoint from $g(A)$.

But anyway, we can think of $g|_A$ as $$g|_A = g(a)  \, \, \quad \forall a \in A.$$ We don't need to care about how $g$ acts on $B\setminus A$. Really this restriction throws away all the information about how $g$ acts $B \setminus A$ and only keeps the information of how $g$ acts on $A$. We formalize the above view by defining $g|_A:A \to C$ by $g|_A 
= g(\mathrm{id}_A)$.

For the sake of visualisation, I'd draw something like this

[image]